# Time complexity which is related to both count of inputs and their size

Tags: algorithm, time, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I have an algorithm where I have multiple tasks and for every task I have to execute as many actions as is the task length in minutes. The action cost is `O(1)`. **Is this pseudo-polynomial, polynomial or exponential algorithm?**

It is very reminiscent of primes naive algorithm or Knapsack dynamic programming solution but this case is slightly different. Consider having 3 tasks and their lengths were `5; 4; 10;`, represented in binary: `101; 100; 1010;`. We have to execute 19 actions. Now if we changed the first task length from `101` to `1101` by adding one bit in front, now we have to execute 27 actions. The number of actions would not double as in case of adding one bit to a number in naive primes solution but rather multiply by factor of `27/19`. If there were even more tasks, the change would be even smaller. In other words the algorithm complexity is related to both length of the inputs and to the number of tasks.

Comment: It is still growing with a factor so, I think your algorithm is exponential

Comment: @Lrrr You mean exponential with respect to input size? Does that mean pseudopolynomial then?

Comment: Yes, I think so

Comment: @Lrrr Thanks, I think so, it just seem strange that there is no estimation of the factor not even a way how to lower and upper bound it.

Comment: @eXPRESS It's easy enough to quote a running time if you want to be precise.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat True, but sadly it is not an option for what I need to demonstrate in my work.

Comment: By "length", do you mean "duration"? Is the length an input to the algorithm? If so, isn't the number of actions you need to perform simply the sum of the tasks' lengths?

Comment: @MoB. Yes, it is, I realize now that I explained it little bit complicated, the described algorithm is actually only one rather simplified step of the whole, because only in this step I am unable to determine its complexity. The important problem I have with it is the notion that 3 tasks of bit length 2 each or 2 tasks of bit length 3 each are the same input length yet after adding one bit to it the factor of exponential increase in computation is different thus related to the number of tasks in the problem.

Comment: But why would you want to represent the complexity in terms of bit-length of the durations of the tasks? It seems much more natural to state it in terms of the values of the durations. So the complexity is just O(sum(durations of tasks)).

Comment: @MoB. I understand, but I am trying to figure out its complexity class. If what you suggest is polynomial/pseudopolynomial/exponential.

Comment: First you need to define your parameters. Here, the most reasonable parameters are the durations of your tasks. So if `n` is the sum of the durations of your tasks, the time complexity is `O(n)`, which of course also makes it polynomial.

Comment: @MoB. I get you now, since I am comparing with algorithm that have as parameter the number of tasks rather than the sum of durations I am trying to finding comparison to them. That is why I think the algorithm is pseudo-polynomial since if the parameters or "inputs" are tasks the algorithm is polynomial to the size of the representation of the inputs. Do you think that is correct assumption?